# Can't find created folder

Tags: android

I create a new folder:

```
String homeDir = "MyApp";
String home = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + homeDir;
File folder = new File(home);
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            return folder.mkdir();
        }
```

But it is never created, why?

Comment: Try using `mkdirs()` instead of `mkdir()`. Also double check whether you'd permission for `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  *mkdirs()* instead of *mkdir()* and also add in ur manifest file the following permission :

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the parent folders do not exist. To create the folder you must then call `folder.mkdirs()` (notice the s).

This is from the [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) documentation:

```
public boolean mkdirs ()
Creates the directory named by this file, creating missing parent directories if necessary. Use mkdir() if you don't want to create missing parents.
```